# Fatal error: Call to a member function display() on a non-object

Tags: php, class, fatal-error

this is my code for creating a list of data elements ! 
 in this below line mentioned there are two error(on the same line)

1)Notice: Undefined offset: 0
2)Fatal error: Call to a member function display() on a non-object

```
  <?php
  class data
  {
     public $num;
     public $Char;


    function __construct()
    {
      $this->num= "null";
      $this->Char= "New Char";    
    }

    public function setInt($int)
    {
      $this->num=$int;
    }

    public function setChar($char)
    {
      $this->Char= $char;
    }


    public function getInt()
    {
      return $this->num;
    }

    public function getChar()
    {
     return $this->Char;
    }

    public function display()
    {
      echo $this->num;
      echo $this->Char;
    }
  }

  class linklist extends data 
  {
    public $DATA;
    private $list;
    private $count;

    function __construct()
    {
      $DATA= new data();
      $list= array();
      $count=0;
    }

    function addData(data $d)
    {
       $this->list[$this->count]= $d;

     $this-> count++;
    }   

    function displayy()
    {
        $d= new data();
        $i=0;
      for($i;$i<=$this->count; $i++)
      {
        $this->list[$i]->display();   //** line with error *** //
      }

    }
  }




?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
   $d= new data();

     //$d->display();

     //$Name= $_POST['fname'];
     //$Age = $_POST['age']; 


     $d->setInt("1");    
     $d->setChar("Ashad");   

     //$d->display();

     $d1= new Data();

     $d1->setInt("2");   
     $d1->setChar("shahrukh");   

     $list = new linklist();

     $list-> addData($d);
     $list->addData($d1);


    $list->displayy();


?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's in the loop where you have `i<=$this->count`, it should be `i < $this->count`. You're accessing one undefined index which is supposed to contain an object and it doesn't.

Comment: i used $i < $this->count !  didnt work same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of `linklist` should be:

```
function __construct()
{
  $this->DATA= new data();
  $this->list= array();
  $this->count=0;
}
```

You have been missing the `$this`

Also note the comment of @N.B. :

```
for($i; $i <= $this->count; $i++)
```

should be

```
for($i = 0; $i < $this->count; $i++)
```